# Migrating Spring Boot Applications to the Latest Java Version (Java 15)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

I have a spring boot project set up to use Java 8 and Kotlin. I want to migrate the project to Java 15, but unfortunately I haven't found any documentation useful for that purpose.

So far i was able to upgrade my Spring boot version from 2.3.3.RELEASE to version 2.4.0 and reference the project to use Java 14 in jvmTarget based on a project example created using the spring initializr.

However, I didn't the find a way to upgrade to Java 15. Any ideas would be very appreciate it.

This is how my build.gradle looks like:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import java.lang.System.getenv

buildscript {
repositories {
    maven {
        url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
    }
 }
 dependencies {
    classpath("org.jmailen.gradle:kotlinter-gradle:3.0.2")
 }
}

plugins {
 id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.0"
 id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.10.RELEASE"
 kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.0"
 kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.0"
 id ("org.owasp.dependencycheck") version "5.3.2"
 id ("com.github.spotbugs") version "4.5.0"
 id ("org.jmailen.kotlinter") version "3.0.2"
 `jacoco`
}

tasks.named<org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun>. 
("bootRun") {
 args("--spring.profiles.active=local")
}

jacoco {
toolVersion = "0.8.6"
}

group = "au.project"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven {
    url = uri("https://...")
    credentials {
        username = getenv("ARTIFACTORY_USER")
        password = getenv("ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD")
     }
  }
}

dependencies {
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter- 
webflux")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module- 
 kotlin")
implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.8.3")
implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin- 
extensions")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
implementation("org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:5.3.2")
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-kotlin:1.4.8")
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:1.4.8")
developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter- 
test") {
    exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
 }
  testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
  testImplementation("com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8:2.27.2")
  testImplementation("com.openpojo:openpojo:0.8.6")
  }

 tasks.withType<Test> {
 useJUnitPlatform()
 }

 tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
 kotlinOptions {
    freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
    jvmTarget = "14"
 }
}
....
```

Note: Chaning the jvmTarget = 15 for the kotlinOptions property within the build.gradle, I am getting the following exception: "Unknown JVM target version: 15 Supported version: 1.6, 1.8, 9,10,11,12,12,14. Does it means Kotlin does not support Java 15?

Comment: Did you download JDK 15 ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Have you tried upgrading jvm target to 15? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 4):

JDK 15 requires Gradle 6.7.x, please update Gradle first, if you haven't done so, yet.

I recommend you use the new [toolchain](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#sec:consuming) feature of Gradle. It will download the required JDK to build your code, if it cannot detect it on the host system, to guarantee that the build is executed with the required JDK version. This also simplifies the right build in different environments with a mixed team.

```
java {
    toolchain {
        // automatically download a jdk for the build if not available
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(11))
    }
}
```

This does not work together with `java.sourceCompatibility` and `java.targetCompatibility`, you would need to remove these configurations.

Comment: Thanks @Simulant,  Does it mean that if the host machine only has Java 15 that will be the one configured by  the toolchain Gradle for my application?

Comment: One more thing, When I change the jvmTarget = 15 for the kotlinOptions property within the build.gradle, I am getting the following exception: "Unknown JVM target version: 15 Supported version: 1.6, 1.8, 9,10,11,12,12,14. Does it means Kotlin does not support Java 15?. What I should do with that property if i use the toolchain?

Comment: yes, I guess this means that Kotlin compiler does not support JDK 15, yet. You can use any lower value. For long term support reasons, I would suggest to use 11 instead of 14.

Comment: Gradle? My Java 15 spring-bopt-app using Maven. Will I have problems with this because I'm using Maven?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to upgrade to latest version of **Gradle, i.e (6.7.x) to support JDK 15.**

Add or update the following lines in **build.gradle** :

```
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_15
java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_15
```

Comment: Thanks @Anish B. Question, my build.gradle file doest not have targetCompatibility, is that something i need to add in addition to the sourceCompatibility that is already in there?

Comment: When I change the jvmTarget = 15 for the kotlinOptions property within the build.gradle, I am getting  the following exception: "Unknown JVM target version: 15 Supported version: 1.6, 1.8, 9,10,11,12,12,14. Does it means Kotlin does not support Java 15?

Comment: @D.B I think so.